# iOS UITextView with email/phone data detector - swap single tap/long tap functions

Tags: objective-c, ios, hyperlink, uitextview, gesture

By default when the UITextView is set to detect email addresses and phone numbers, it provides the following built-in functions :

Single tap : Email - open new message in mail app; Phone - alert dialog for Cancel or Call

Long tap : Email - action sheet menu options; Phone - action sheet menu options

What I'd like to do is to swap these functions around so that the single tap provides the action sheet menu options rather than a long tap.  Is this possible?  How would I go about this?

Comment: trying to do something similar, did you find a solution?